# How to create a timer which can be used multiple times in Java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I want to run a timer for multiple requests. If I get a request I will be running the timer for `1000ms` in between if I get another request I need to update the timer. If I didn't get any request for `1000ms` I need to exit the process.

How to implement such a timer? I can't perform the operation with Timer task.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you paste the code of what you've attempted?  It will help the community to help you.

Comment: Show at least the code skeleton you want to execute it this cannot be a `TimerTask`.

Comment: I tried with Timer Task and the code snippet is shared below.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the use of a multiple timer?  What are you executing after the timer expires?  Why can't you create a new timer for each request?  We can't help you unless we understand the problem you're trying to solve, not just your attempted solution.

Comment: Let me explain with a simple scenario, I will be getting multiple response from a device. Each response should be received within 1000ms (i.e) the time interval between 1st response and 2nd response can be maximum 999ms, if the response is not received within 1000ms it must be stopped and display a notification like response timeout. In timertask implementation I dont have an option to check whether the timer is running!!! If i cancel the timer without running throws Nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ScheduledExecutorService

Sample bellow:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class A {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable  terminate = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Terminate task executed");
        }
    };
    ScheduledExecutorService  timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ScheduledFuture<?> futureTask = timer.schedule(terminate, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    futureTask.cancel(true);
    System.out.println("Timer Canceled");
    futureTask = timer.schedule(terminate, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    futureTask.cancel(true);
    System.out.println("Timer Canceled");
  }

}
```

If you run it, you will see terminate task is never run because it is canceled before the 1 SEC passes